# How to replace values in a column with NULLs in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a better way to replace a column values with NULLs than the code below

```
select 
    case when A is not NULL end as columnname
```

I tried using `update` function but I realised that works only for strings.

Comment: Update should still work -- just to confirm, are you trying to replace a null value with something else, or some other value with null?

Comment: UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = NULL WHERE condition

Comment: I think we need some more information. `UPDATE MyTable SET intField = NULL, StringField=NULL, DateField = NULL` is absolutely doable, as long as the fields were defined as nullable.  To just return a NULL in place of a value in your query, you can do something like `SELECT intField, NULL as StringField, NULL as DateField FROM MyTable`

Comment: If what you want to do is only return values where they are not null, try `SELECT A From MyTable WHERE A IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @istrupin I want to replace other values with null

Comment: @LaughingVergil Will `UPDATE MyTable SET intField = NULL, StringField=NULL, DateField = NULL` work even if I dont add a `where` condition?

Comment: It would work, but it will change that field to NULL in all rows. If you need it restricted, see my answer below for examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace values with NULL in a SQL Table, the basic form of the query is:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET FieldName = NULL
[WHERE FieldName = <ValueToReplace>]
```

This can get more complex if you want to replace specific values with NULL in multiple fields at once. This can be handled by either using the above statement once for each field, or by using CASE statements on the update.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET FieldName1 = CASE WHEN FieldName1 = '' THEN NULL ELSE FieldName1 END,
    FieldName2 = CASE WHEN FieldName2 = -1 THEN NULL ELSE FieldName2 END
```

If you want to NULL out whatever value in specific rows, the query would look more like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET FieldName1 = NULL,
    FieldName2 = NULL
WHERE RowID IN (1,6,22,405)
```

Comment: Thank you. That answers all my questions